# Need help in my script , for some reason if statement not working

Tags: powershell, split, csplit

In put file. I am looking for largest size value under each backup type ( db2, rman or file ) for each server. same server may have multiple entry with different value for same backup type.

```
hup00010.corpads.local 84675276 MN_UNIX_NP_7_Days        manual 02/24/2022 04/21/2022 03/31/2022         disk 1645678853              82 MB RMAN:PFDPRE01_je0mjj9l_1_1    MNBDD3302P.corpads.local
hup00010.corpads.local 82578060 MN_DB_ORA MN_DB Clone_DR manual 02/24/2022 04/21/2022 04/21/2022         disk 1645678854 Clone_DR     80 MB RMAN:PFDPRE01_jf0mjj9l_1_1    JCBDD1300P.corpads.local
bpdppa301p.corpads.local 82578060 MN_DB_ORA                manual 02/24/2022 04/21/2022 03/31/2022         disk 1645678854              80 MB RMAN:PFDPRE01_jf0mjj9l_1_1    MNBDD3302P.corpads.local
hup00010.corpads.local 86929680 JC_UNIX_FS01_INCR JC_FS UNIX_FS01_INCR incr 02/24/2022 03/30/2022 03/30/2022  disk 1645678800 backup 84 MB /dbwsrp01/dbwsrp01         MNBDD3302P.corpads.local
bpdppa301p.corpads.local 86929680 JC_UNIX_FS01_INCR JC_FS UNIX_FS01_INCR incr 02/24/2022 03/30/2022 03/30/2022  disk 1645678800 backup 84 MB /dbwsrp01/dbwsrp01           JCBDD1300P.corpads.local
```

My code

```
$out=Get-Content C:\my\scripts\test2.txt
$ht = @{}
$arr = @()
$today = Get-Date
foreach ( $line in $out){
              $arr=$line.Split(" ")
              if ( $arr[0] -ne "nwsppl300p.corpads.local"){
              $mn=$line -csplit "incr|full|manual"
              $md=$mn[1] -split "\s{1,}"
              if ($line -match  '.*( backup |Clone_DR ).*') {$btype=$md[9]} else {$btype=$md[8]}
              
              $date =$mn[1].split(" ")[2]
              $newdate=[Datetime]::ParseExact($date, 'MM/dd/yyyy', $null)
              $diff = New-TimeSpan -Start $today -end $newdate
              #### look for one year only ########
              if ( $diff.Days -lt 400 ) {
                   if ( $arr[12] -ne "Clone_DR") {
                        if ($arr[0] -notin $ht.keys){
                                                 $ht[$arr[0]] = @{}
                                                 #$ht[$arr[0]]['size'] = $arr[1]
                                                 
                                                 if ($btype -match "DB2") {
                                                                            
                                                                            $ht[$arr[0]]['Db2size'] = $arr[1]
                                                                            
                                                                             }
                                                                             if ($btype -match "RMAN") {
                                                                             
                                                                            
                                                                             $ht[$arr[0]]['RMANsize'] = $arr[1]
                                                                            
                                                                             } 
                                                                             
                                                                            if  ($btype -notmatch "RMAN" -and $btype -notmatch "DB2" ){
                                                                             
                                                                             $ht[$arr[0]]['Filesize'] = $arr[1]
                                                                            
                                                                             }

                                                 
                                                 } else {
                                                         
                                                          #####
                                                          if ($btype -match "DB2" -and $arr[1] > $ht[$arr[0]]['Db2size'] ) {
                                                                            $ht[$arr[0]]['Db2size'] = $arr[1]
                                                                            
                                                                             }
                                                                             if ($btype -match "RMAN" -and $arr[1] > $ht[$arr[0]]['RMANsize']) {
                                                                             $ht[$arr[0]]['RMANsize'] = $arr[1]
                                                                             
                                                                             } 
                                                                             if  ($btype -notmatch "RMAN" -and $btype -notmatch "DB2" -and $arr[1] > $ht[$arr[0]]['Filesize']  ){
                                                                                                      
                                                                             
                                                                             $ht[$arr[0]]['Filesize'] = $arr[1]
                                                                                           
                                                                                                                 
                                                                             }

                                                          ####
                                                    }
                                                    

                                                    }  ###clone_dr
                                                    }   ###less than 400
                          } ### chcking for networker server
                          } #### looping thru file

                                                   
write-host "=================================In MB ==============================================="
write-host "===ServerName==============OverAllsize======DB2size===========RMANsize========FileSize"
write-host "======================================================================================"
 $ht.GetEnumerator()|Sort-Object {$_.name} -Descending | ForEach-Object  {
 $total = $_.value.Db2size + $_.value.RMANsize + $_.value.Filesize
 "{0,-25}     {1:n2}          {2:n2}            {3:n2}            {4:n2}" -f $_.name,$($total/1024/1024),$($_.value.Db2size/1024/1024),$($_.value.RMANsize/1024/1024),$($_.value.Filesize/1024/1024)}
```

## output is

PS C:\my\scripts> .\get_client_max_size.ps1

```
=================================In MB ===============================================
===ServerName==============OverAllsize======DB2size===========RMANsize========FileSize
======================================================================================
hup00010.corpads.local        80.75          0.00            80.75            0.00
bpdppa301p.corpads.local      78.75          0.00            78.75            0.00
```

server bpdppa301p.corpads.local has size for file level backup but it will not show up.
Have issue with code "($btype -notmatch "RMAN" -and $btype -notmatch "DB2" -and $arr[1] > $ht[$arr[0]]['Filesize']" here $arr[1] > $ht[$arr[0]]['Filesize'] does not like ??? any idea?

Comment: You should really condense your code to where the problem lies. Are you looking for the comparison operators? I.e. comparing what is bigger than what? You should be using `-GT`, and not `>`.

Comment: I strongly recommend parsing each line to objects, then performing comparisons on the objects. Given the format you could do RegEx matching to get those objects.

Comment: your data LOOKS like it was a tab-delimited data set without a header line. **_is it?_**

Comment: wow , looks like my bran need WHISKY , yes i used -GT all look good

Comment: Your overall size is going to be grossly wrong because you store everything as a string, so when you try to add them all it's just concatenating several strings and not adding numbers. Change your second to last line to `$total = 0 + $_.value.Db2size + $_.value.RMANsize + $_.value.Filesize` so it knows to treat them like numbers.